# Oracle Forms running on java 6 Update 45

Tags: java, forms, oracle, oracle11g

I have one program, I maintain, that was originally written in Oracle Forms 6i.  A while ago I migrated it to 11g.  Our users access this Oracle Forms program through their Internet Explorer browser on their Windows 7 machines.

The problem has been that the program only seems to run well for our users, when they have Java 6 Update 45, installed on their machines.  Going to a newer version causes problems.

Today, I wanted to get this resolved, so I updated my PC to Java 8.31, and attempted to access my Oracle forms program using IE.  (Thanks to [Viewing oracle app and getting: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.forms.engine.Main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492400/viewing-oracle-app-and-getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-oracle-forms-e) I was able to get the form running again in my web browser.)

When my form ran, I found the tab key wouldn't advance to the next field on the login dialogue box.  But after I logged in the tab key worked.  (The tab key initially not working is a small thing, but it has really annoyed some of our users.)

I then used several different forms.  Some worked just fine, no problems.   But then when I clicked a button, on one form, it would endlessly try to complete a request; to the point that I couldn't even close the web browser to stop it.  (Finally I just used task manager to end my web browser’s process.)   This seemed to go in line with what some of our users have reported:  (when attempting to use the latest Java) that the Oracle forms application just stops working completely after a while.

Because of these issues our users want to keep Java 6 Update 45 on their machines.  I know this is a major security hole, but I haven’t quite nailed down what the solution to it is.

Has anyone else had a similar issue?  We're running Oracle Fusion Middleware 11; specifically Forms Services version 11.1.2.0.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well this may not be a question that needs answering after all.

I've done some more testing since asking this.  Besides the login dialogue box (not responding, as it should, to the tab key) everything else works just as it should.

I still have one form that hangs; but that’s all (and it may be caused by something else).  All my other forms seem to work just fine.

I talked with one of my co-workers, and I realized we really need to investigate and determine what version of Java our users really are using.  They may not have used the most recent version of Java; which I used with success, today.  Or some may be already on it; and that's why they aren't complaining.

At any rate more research, is needed on my part.  Thanks to all who read this.  If any of you have had similar experience in something like this, still feel welcome to answer/comment.

Comment: Welcome to the wacky world of java versions and browser version! When a system is built it is built with at least some assumptions.  It sounds like you are running some sort of embeded java program inside the browser ( YIKES ) and then browser versions change and suddenly things stop working.  In this mode EVERYTHING has to be updated in lock-step.

Comment: “YIKES” is the very best way to describe any Oracle forms application; I agree.   That everything would work well with Java/Oracle once it has been updated lock-step, if only that were true…